# Windows 7 photo gallery corrupts my images

Tags: troubleshooting, data-corruption, file-transfer, windows-7

My win7 photo gallery started to corrupt my photos when I open up them.

I am copying from cameras memory card to my external driver and start to view them with win7 photo gallery they start to corrupt. I mean random lines and colors appear at some area of the photo. Not only jpegs but also raw files too are effected.

When I re-copy photos from memory card to another folder, it seems ok. I view them with windows photo gallery, no corruption!! But when I copy the files to external drive and open-up them with windows photo gallery they get corrupted again!!!!

Why?

Comment: sounds like the problem is with the harddrive. What model is it? btw are tehy corrupted when you copy them to the internal drive and view them? (if yes, the files are corrupted, if no, the files are not corrupted but the viewer just skips data packets as it is reading them).

Comment: I mean, when you copy from the external drive to internal, after seeing them as corrupted

Comment: The common factor in the corruption is the external drive since the problem occurs when the camera/card is not involved (copying from local disk to external disk).  Unless there's evidence to show the file being changed *after* it hits the external disk then it's unlikely to be WLPG.  As a general point this might get a better response from SuperUser...

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a classic failing harddrive. 
My first recommendation is to BACK UP EVERYTHING right now to an external hard drive. If this is the case, you will likely be loosing bits of data here and there from any old files on your drive.

After you've backed up you have several options available to you

You can:

- Review windows event logs and look for any [disk errors](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262448) in them
- Run the [disk manufacturers software diagnostics utility](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/tp/tophddiag.htm)
- Attempt to fix any corrupted sectors on your harddrive using inbuilt tools for windows such as '[chkdsk](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/using-windows-7-how-do-i-run-chkdsk/a68b3e4d-1a42-e011-9767-d8d385dcbb12)'
- Download and use [data recovery software](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/filerecovery/tp/free-file-recovery-programs.htm) (if needed)

  - additionally, if the files are critical you can send the drive to a data recovery specialist and they'll be able to recover files for you (although at quite a price). The rule of thumb here though is If the components in your drive are still functioning, you can recover the data yourself. If there is mechanical damage, send it to the pros

There are [numerous causes](http://users.iafrica.com/c/cq/cquirke/baddata.htm) for this, in the end though the best thing you can do is replace the harddrive after you've recovered as much data from it as possible.

Hope that helps,
Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

How did you transfer the pics?  What I doing is I connect the USB cable from PC to the camera and I transfer the photos using the Software provided by the manufacturer. (e.g. Nikon NEX Capture)  Why? because doing that would make me more ensure that the files will not be corrupted.  I do not just select the photos from the folder of the memory card and just drag it to the folder I want.  Some details and information of the image may be corrupted and the quality may be affected.